# Are there any good BigData/IoT reference architectures?

Tags: architecture, iot, bigdata

I am looking for some reference architectures for an application that has to be:

- geo scalable : allows for ingestion of data from nodes that are
  spread across the globe (possibly like IoT).
- semi-structured data : data that is not all sorted out. scope for new devices to send data that is not yet known
- have a single-pane/portal/api that allows for querying aggregated data from different locations.

(Update):
Since posting this question, I have been reading through a few presentation and youtube videos. So far I have gathered the following:

Option 1: Use a customized solution stack from a cloud vendor like Amazon, Azure. To quickly bootstrap, there are also consulting firms that specialize in one of these cloud solutions.

Option 2: Build using open-source stacks. Couple of interesting architectures are : SMACK , Lambda.

Any help that you could provide in pointing to the right links/books/blogs or your notes/comments from which I could derive an reference architecture will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are platforms which can be used for such requirements and best supported platforms with required tools/technologies are offered by AWS (https://aws.amazon.com/iot/) and Microsoft (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/suites/iot-suite/). You still need to develop your custom app with specific business logic to your solution requirements and you must take advantage of schema less database (NoSql) for developing such solution where data structures are unknown at this stage.

You can also consider following Microservices architecture for exposing APIs to be integrated with 3rd party apps.

Comment: Thanks Gurdev. The suggestion to go with Micro-services is excellent. In-fact, once a tech stack (reference) is identified, I would like to look at using them over kubernetes (preferably).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is too late an answer. I don't have experience with any cloud vendor IoT offering, so cant help there.

- The SMACK stack is pretty popular, but you may not need all of it as is.
- The key parts of that architecture are Spark for real-time analytics, Kafka for the messaging bus and Cassandra for the database layer.
- Mesos is a management framework, you can replace with Kubernetes
- Akka is a scale/Java language framework, not sure what your preferred language of choice is.